# Employee Satisfaction data collected at two times- samples overlap but are not paired by case-How to compare t1 to t2

Tags: paired-data, independence

It feels like this should be a no-brainer but I just can't see it.  I collected employee satisfaction data in year 1 and year 2.  I cannot connect subjects across years because I did not assign or manufacture an ID for each person, but I know that some people answered in both years, some answered only in year 1 and some answered only in year two.  I want to compare satisfaction at time 1 to satisfaction at time 2...but the data is not functionally paired and not really independent.  Some of the variables I want to compare are ordinal and some are scale- what stats should I use?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site, Amy. FWIW, it's not clear to me that this is a no-brainer.

Comment: Thanks John :-)

Comment: Do you know how many people overlapped, btw?

Comment: Most of the sample overlapped.   78% response rate (of all employees) at time 1 and 65% response rate (of all employees) at time  2… some new hires and some retirees. So almost every one who answered at time two also answered at time one.